# Arduino Esp8266 Signal(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) can’t compile

Tags: esp8266

Trying to compile a program containing the statement SIGNAL(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) written for arduino. But I want to use it on an esp8266 board. The code will compile  for Arduino uno. But I get an error “expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(‘ token when I try to compile for a Wemos D1 board. Can anyone help me convert the statement to pass the compile test. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

That instruction is for setting up an interrupt handler for the timer. It is very much specific to the AVR.

There's a lot more to do that just adjust that one statememt - you have to completely rewrite the whole of the timer code that you're using to operate with the ESP8266 SDK calls.

Without knowing what your code intends to achieve it's impossible to help you further, but [this library](https://github.com/khoih-prog/ESP8266TimerInterrupt) may be of help to you.